# How do I declare a global variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a multi-form project in vb.net.  A few of the forms use serial port communication, and I open the serial port on the form_load event on each form.  Part of opening the serial port is specifying baudrate, port name, etc.

I might have the use this project on a few computers, so I want to make a string that contains the com port (i.e. "COM3") that I can use when opening the COM port.  This way, when I deploy on a different computer, all I have to do is edit the one string variable.  How would I define the string so that it can be used on every form the in the project, and how would I call that string on each form?  Also, where would I define it?  On the first form that loads?

Comment: You could created a `Variables.vb` file and define everything you need in there? If you make it a module it should be easy to refer to it over your project

Comment: Have you look into using the config file?